# Azure Data Factory, Iterate through list from RESTFUL APIs call

Tags: sql, api, rest, azure-data-factory

Hello I am new to ADF an I am working on a project that has this scenario.
I am working with RESTFUL APIs requests, so basically we have a use case that requires us to pull data for all those updated employees in a range of a month with specific columns and insert that data to a SQL table monthly.

What I have tried:

- I have created a pipeline in ADF that makes the first RESTFUL request to get all the employees that where updated for the month, but that gives me only Employees IDs column, I have saved these IDs to a temp table in SQL.
- Created a pipeline that includes Lookup Activity, Set Variable Activity , and a ForEach Activity. Lookup activity here takes all Employees Ids updated, I have set the variable to pick the output of the Lookup, also Set variable2 is being assigned to the ForEachXRefCode Loop

[image]
now the tricky part here is that the HR portal DayForce that we are making the RESTFUL APIs request is giving us only **Employees ID** column that were updated in a range of a month and not the columns I am looking to pull, which are.

EmployeeID
,FirstName
,MiddleName
,LastName
,BusinessEmail
,BusinessPhone
,HomeEmail
,HomePhone
,CellPhone
,Status]
,JobTitle
,Department
,Office

according to them, we would need to make separate RESTFUL API calls for each EmployeeID to get columns we need , but there could be more than 100 employees changed during that month and is impossible to do 100 RESTFUL APIs requests separately. Is there any possibility with ADF using pipelines that I can iterate to this list of updated employees Ids and make single calls for each row automatically take that employee ID make a single call for it retrieve the columns we need and insert that to the table in SQL?

Thank You.

Comment: We can Foreach Employees ID list and then concatenate the query string in the Web activity, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use Web activity and Stored procedure activity to achieve that.

I create a simple test. First create a table:

```sql
Create table dbo.emp(
    empId int,
    empName varchar(255)
)
```

create a stored procedure

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspEmp] @empId NVARCHAR(255),@empName VARCHAR(255)
AS  

    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO dbo.emp values(@empId,@empName)
    END
GO
```

Then we can use ADF to achieve our target.

1. My Lookup activity return a list `[{empId:'1001'},{empId:'1002'},{empId:'1003'}]`.
   [image]
2. Then we can do foreach at ForEach1 activity via expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` to get empId.
   [image]
3. Inside the  ForEach1 activity. We can use `@concat('http://localhost:8080/servletdemo/getEmp?empId=',item().empId)` to concatenate a query string at Web1 activity.
   [image]
4. At `Stored procedure1` activity, we can get the output of Web1 activity
   [image]

Comment: I kind understand what are you trying to say with this, but how would I retrieve other columns based on their Emp ID updated because for me to get other columns I need to make different API requests, for now I only have EmpID updated monthly from the API request

Comment: Do you mean that you can't change the query parameters of the Rest API inside the ForEach1 activity. to get other informations including EmpID?

Comment: Basically I have two separate REST APIs that I would like to combine and retrieve one table, I have the first request:
https://dayforcehcm.com/Api/company/V1/Employees?filterUpdatedStartDate=2021-03-01T00%3A00%3A01&filterUpdatedEndDate=2021-03-01T23%3A59%3A59
this gives me the updated employees, and I am able to save them in SQL table, but for me to get the columns I need, I need another request like this:
https://dayforcehcm.com/Api/company/V1/Employees/1001?expand=FirstName %2CLastName%2CBusinessEmail%2CBusinessPhone etc, as you see it restricts me to filter to one single employee
Thanks

Comment: I'm sure this can be achieved in a single pipeline - can you share the parameters and output of the first API call and same for the second?

Answer (score 0):

THe prob using look along with foreach activity is, lookup has limitation to hold only 5000 rows.